# How to compare the border thickness of a jLabel?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, netbeans

I have an array of jLabels with the names of various players contained in a DoubleLinkedList. The jLabels have borders of 1px thickness. The border is supposed to change to 3px when it is the players turn. I haven't been able to compare successfully if the border is 3px thus I cannot switch turns. The variable m is what I need to return the index of label with the 3px border. I would really appreciate the help.

```
int m;

for (m = 0; m < jlNombresArray.size(); m++) {
    if(jlNombresArray.get(m).getBorder().equals(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(240, 240, 240), 3))) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: My suggestion: separate your game model from your view so that your program doesn't depend on the current state of the JLabel border thickness. Rather it checks the model's state, and then uses it to set the label border's thickness. This will result in cleaner, easier to enhance and debug code.

Comment: The model will contain a list of Player objects, one of which is designated as having a turn. When the model's state changes -- when a new Player has their turn, the view is notified and changes the state of the appropriate labels, again depending on what it finds to be the model's state.

Comment: you are absolutely right  thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold a selection state in your data model.

```
int selectedPlayerIndex = -1;

void changePlayerView(int playerIndex) {
    if (selectedPlayerIndex != -1) {
        jlNombresArray.get(selectedPlayerIndex).setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 240, 240), 1));
    }
    selectedPlayerIndex = playerIndex;
    if (selectedPlayerIndex != -1) {
        jlNombresArray.get(selectedPlayerIndex).setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 240, 240), 3));
    }
    ... repaint ...
}
```

Comment: this is might work with some adjusting since i need the integer of the player but thank you for your help. I will apply this method into my code :)